# node.js mySQL NOW() is giving the wrong date

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, datetime

I have a web application which runs a mix of MySQL, PHP, and node.js. MySQL and PHP report the right times for me, but I can't seem to figure out how to get node.js to comply.

Mysql Now() result

```
MariaDB [seo]> select NOW();
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2014-10-20 22:51:53 |
```

Also, an SQL query executed from my PHP code that runs NOW(), gives the date seen above.

However, when node executes NOW() from within an SQL query, I get a date that is 3 hours in the future.

I have looked around and can't seem to find a solution. I have tried setting the environment variable for node as follows..

```
process.env.TZ = 'America/New_York';
```

But it doesn't appear to make a difference. My node scripts are not perpetually running, they are only invoked through commands/shell scripts.

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleString(); 
var j = d.toISOString(); 
var l = d.toUTCString(); 
console.log('toLocaleString(): ' + n + ', toISOString(): ' + j + ', toUTCString(): ' + l);
```

Gives the output:

```
toLocaleString(): Mon Oct 20 2014 22:51:53 GMT-0400 (EDT), toISOString(): 2014-10-21T02:51:53.489Z, toUTCString(): Tue, 21 Oct 2014 02:51:53 GMT
```

I'm really not sure why they are all over the place. Not sure what to configure as the answers I see regarding Dates in node are all over the place. And my main confusion when running an SQL query in node (with sequelize), NOW() is inserting a date 3 hours off. Anyways, if anybody could help it would definitely be appreciated.

Comment: Your "toLocaleString" call seems to be outputting the date as you expect. Read up on dates in javascript - they are always stored in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure your dates are stored in UTC. Then upon retrieval format the date as you wish.